# script to tar and copy directories

Tags: unix, copy, tar, shell

Hey, I think the best way to ask this question is to show what I need to happen.

I need to go from:

```
Project_Direcory
   Project
      Solution1
      Solution2
      Solution3
```

To:

```
Project_Direcory
   Project.tar.gz
   Solution1.tar.gz
   Solution2.tar.gz
   Solution3.tar.gz
```

Project.tar.gz still contains all the Solution directories. I am having issues where it is copying files that are inside of the solution directories and placing them in the Project_Directory. There are also some text files in Project, that should not be copied. I am currently trying:

```
for file in $(find /place/* -type d);do tar zcf  ${file}.tar.gz $file;done
for file in $(find /place/* );do mv  ${file} /place;done
for file in $(find /place/* -type d);do cp -r  ${file} /place;done
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find -maxdepth 2` to restrict the depth.